# How to debug tsx files when using webpack

Tags: debugging, reactjs, typescript, webpack, tsc

I'm new to front-end development.

I write some reactjs component in tsx format. this is one of my tsx files:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {observer} from "mobx-react";
import {observable} from "mobx";
import {TileGrid, Tile} from "./GridStack"




@observer
export class Dashboard extends React.Component<any, any>{

    addTiles() {

        this.props.data.push(
            {title: "I'm a !"}
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>I'm dashboard !</h1>
                <button onClick={this.addTiles.bind(this)}>Add some tiles</button>
                <TileGrid columnCount="12">
                    {this.props.data.map((x) => {
                        return (
                            <Tile x="1" minWidth="2" minHeight="3">
                                {x.title}
                            </Tile>
                        )
                    })}
                </TileGrid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see it has Node Module format. and it has dependency to GridStack module.

It's my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "jsx": "react"

    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "static"
    ]
}
```

the output js files contain commands like **reuqire(...)** that is undefinded for browsers.

to achieve this problem I decided to use **webpack** .

It fix that issue but now I faced with a new problem.

I can't debug **GridStack.tsx** file because webpack just allow me to debug root level tsx file.

this is my webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './TS/controllers/App.tsx',
    output: {
        filename: './dist/app.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.Webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.tsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                    loader: 'ts-loader'
                }
        ],
        preLoaders: [
                // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
                { test: /\.tsx$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Bundling and packing isn't my current issue I just need to have js files that are **browser friendly** and be able to **debug each tsx files**.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: we debug on ts files without needing to do any special. we don't use the preloader but we do use awesome-ts-loader instead of ts-loader. If that doesn't solve it I can take a deeper look in our repo

Comment: Thanks @mweststrate. I've solved my problem by using requirejs. But I will use awesome-ts-loader. Which plugin do you use for converting ts files to browser friendly js ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for those who have the same problem.
The order of **extensions** is important.
I mentioned 'tsx' first and then other types.
when compileOnSave option set true, each tsx file will have a correspondence js file. in this situation when the .js extension comes earlier Webpack grab the js file instead of tsx file.